# How to read text files in python with specified condition?

Tags: python

I have a text file and I want to extract the number of the line that contains certain phrases (ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom) and K_POINTS (automatic)).

```
n = -1
with open(filename) as f:
     for line in f:
          n += 1
          if line  == "ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)":
               print('test1')
               start = n
          elif line  == "K_POINTS (automatic)":
               print('test2')
               end = n

print(start, end)
```

My problem is that python does not go inside the if statements (i.e. test1 and test2 are not printed).

But I am sure that filename contain the phrases, this is small part of filename:

0.000000613   0.000000613   1.022009120

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)

C        1.696797551   1.714436737  -0.068349117

Comment: Use `in` like, `if "ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)" in line:..print('test1')..` `==` will check for the equality of the two strings, as in if `line` is exactly equal to the string `"ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)"` also, the `line` may have `newlines` So if you just want to check the occurrence of a substring in a line, then use `in`

Comment: try to check the uppercase or lowercase of the texts. convert the line as complete uppercase

Comment: @SallyZeitler God no!, you can't use `is` instead of `==`. `is` is for identify check, and for immutable types `a is b` may or may not be True, if both `a` and `b` are equal, but it is definitely not what it is used for, and don't use `is` for equality check, ever

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: your condition is not met. `"=="` checks for equality, which for several reasons may not be true in your case (see comments).

When checking for a string in a line of a file I would try this:

```
n=-1
with open(filename) as f:
     for line in f:
          n += 1
          if  "ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)" in line:
               print('test1')
               start = n
```